# How to index a list of tf.keras.layers.Layer with a TensorFlow Tensor inside a tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a list of tf.keras.layers.Layer that I want to index based off of an index tensor inside a tf.function. Ideally like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from typing import List

@tf.function
def compute_single_output(heads: List[layers.Layer], index_tensor: tf.Tensor, input: tf.Tensor):
    logit = heads[index_tensor](input)
    return logit
```

But I get this:

```
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor
```

Is there any way to set this up so that I can do it? tf.gather won't work for a list of Layers. TF Lookup table wouldn't work either. I tried using a dict of `heads` instead of a list, also didn't work.

Only thing that works is to iterate over the list in a Python for loop, but this accumulates CPU RAM per iteration over the loop (because autograph can't convert `heads` into a tensor, it can't use tf.while_loop, see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#loops for more info):

```
@tf.function
def compute_single_output(heads: List[layers.Layer], index_tensor: tf.Tensor, input: tf.Tensor):
    logit = tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.float32)
    m = tf.constant(0)
    for head in heads:
        if m == index_tensor:
            logit = head(input)
        else:
            pass
        m += 1
    return logit
```

I expect to be running this function for a long time, so I can't afford to accumulate memory indefinitely.

Comment: make `index_tensor: int`?

Comment: `index_tensor` comes from iterating over a tf.data.Dataset, so it can't be int unfortunately

Comment: I can make `heads` a different container of Layers though (instead of list), if that will help

Comment: Did you look at `tf.switch_case`? or passing the input to all the N layers and getting N outputs, and doing tf.gather during loss calculation?

Comment: tf.switch_case might work but will require me to make a new one every time `input` changes (i.e. every forward pass). But I will test to see if that's worth it. Thanks. 2nd idea would eat up too much GPU RAM

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks to be very slow as it seems to be re-trace compiling every iteration.

I think One-Hot based indexing / control flow inside a tf.function is a common idea in deep learning. It would be great if the TF team made this easier / doable to implement for efficient computation

Comment: post this bug in tensorflow issues, lets see what they comeup with.

Comment: Alright done: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58965

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is solvable with the Functional API right? Like have a branch per head and then use `index_tensor` to determine which branch to take